# Is there a name for this type of integral $\int_a^b \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{1-P(x)^2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Given a polynomial of **arbitrary** degree, $P(x)$, on $[a,b]$ is there a name for this type of integral:

$$\int_a^b \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{1-P(x)^2}}dx$$

Comment: Since you are talking about a polynomial, the degree is *finite*, right? In principle you can make a substitution $P(x)=\cos t$ and $\sqrt{1-P^2}=\sin t$ or the other way around. However, finding $x=F(t)$ and $dx=f(t) dt$ might prove very difficult in the general case.

Comment: @YuriyS thanks. Yes, the degree is finite. In practice, it would be < 5, if that' helps. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ Bey, if the degree is $<5$ then the corresponding polynomial equation can be solved in radicals, so you can probably find $x(t)$. However, it may be a horrible combination of cube and square roots, which will be a huge pain to differentiate